# subversion: quickly load previous revisions

Tags: svn

Say I'm working on a certain SVN branch and after a few commits I would like rerun some tests with my original revision, say R4. More specifically, I would like to compile the code of R4, run some test cases, and then "reload" the branch I was working on, say R8, which is fully commited, i.e. `svn status` does not return anything. How should I quickly load R4, run some tests, then jump back R8?

Thanks

-C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To switch between branches use [`svn switch`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.switchwc.html):

```
Switch to the Branch A:
$ svn switch /project/branchA

Switch to the Branch B:
$ svn switch /project/branchB
```

To switch between revisions in the same branch (more correctly -- update to a specific revision) use [`svn up -r`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.history.html#svn.tour.history.snapshots):

```
Update to revision 123:
$ svn up -r 123

Update to revision 456:
$ svn up -r 456
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if TortoiseSVN is quick enough for you, but branch switching is simple enough using that tool.